# Can I cover an evergreen shrub in winter?

Tags: plant-health, leaves, shrubs, broad-leaved-evergreens, evergreens

I have a small evergreen shrub that gets frost burn in winter. I had been told to use tar paper on it over winter, but I was concerned that since it is a broad-leaved evergreen it might need light in winter. Is there a good way to cover it that doesn't set it back?

Comment: Out of interest, do you know what type of evergreen shrub we're talking about here? Also could you please post a photo on the evergreen shrub in question...

Comment: When plants go into winter dormancy they need little to no light.  So it should be good.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Personally I would wrap the shrub, but leave the top open to the elements -- unless heavy snow load, damage, is a problem in your area, or the shrub you're protecting is susceptible to snow damage...

Bang into the ground a number of suitably sized timber stakes around the shrub:

- Suitably sized timber stakes = 1inch x 1inch (25mm x 25mm) to 2inch x 2inch (50mm x 50mm), with a point cut in one end -- this will make driving them into the ground that much easier.
- Cut the timber stakes to the height of the shrub you're protecting + 12inchs (300mm) minimum --  this will allow at least 12inchs (300mm) of the stakes to be embedded into the ground, thus giving your "protection system" adequate strength.

**For maximum Wintertime protection:**

- Install the stakes about 6 to 8inches (150 to 200mm) away from the shrub you're protecting.
- Wrap the stakes with something like:

  - Burlap.
  - A horticultural thermal/fleece blanket.
  - Chicken wire.
  - Plastic mesh.
- Fill the enclosure with something like:

  - Non-diseased Autumn fall leaves.
  - Straw.

**For minimum to moderate Wintertime protection:**

- Install the stakes as close as you can to the shrub you're protecting.
- Wrap the stakes with something like:

  - Burlap.
  - A horticultural thermal/fleece blanket.

The below articles, documents may also prove helpful/useful:

- [Protecting Trees and Shrubs Against Winter Damage](http://www.extension.umn.edu/garden/yard-garden/trees-shrubs/protecting-from-winter-damage/)
- [Winter Protection for Landscape Plants](http://osufacts.okstate.edu/docushare/dsweb/Get/Document-1121/HLA-6404web.pdf) (direct link to PDF)
- [Preventing Winter Injury to Landscape Plants](http://www.unce.unr.edu/publications/files/ho/other/fs8874.pdf) (direct link to PDF)
- [Cold weather - BBC Gardening Guides](http://www.bbc.co.uk/gardening/basics/weather_coldweather.shtml)