# Brown turkey fig dormancy time

Tags: fruit-trees, plant-health, figs

We picked up a brown turkey fig tree last summer. We plan on keeping it in a large pot rather than in the ground. We have a small space and understand they have a good sized root system. Plus we live in an iffy area for this tree when it comes to overnight lows (Kootenays in BC Canada).

At the end of year wrap up we brought it inside rather than protecting it outside. The location it's been in has not allowed the tree to go dormant and instead it's growing...too well!

My question is what should we do to give it the best chance this summer? Did we harm its year? Should we prune it now and get it outside (slowly) to give it some cold time? Or let it be and just move it out in when it's warm?

Comment: Just plant it out when it gets warm, it will be a monster!

Answer (score 3):

According to the information I have, fig trees do not need to be pruned except in order to be turned into the desired shape when young. If you don't particularly have a desired shape, then you wouldn't need to prune it - which would solve that part of the problem.

If the tree is not dormant, don't put it outside in the cold weather - without experiencing the change of the seasons and going dormant, it is not prepared for the cold. Wait until the warm weather so that the temperature is in tune with the stage that the tree is at.

See this other question for general young-fig-tree care:
[How do I care for a young fig tree?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/2466/how-do-i-care-for-a-young-fig-tree?rq=1)